# How to correctly define typings for non-ts react components that are a key of another react component

Tags: reactjs, typescript, ecmascript-6

So I have a project where I have some react components that look like this (all in the same file List.js):

```
export default class List extends Component {
render(){//stuff}
}

List.Item = (props, context) => {
//function component stuff
}
```

Basically there's a react function component as a key of another react component if that makes sense. This is something I can't change, it's part of a library I am using. I'm trying to define a index.d.ts for this library, but when I try to define "List" like so:

```
//in index.d.ts

export as namespace myLibrary

export declare class List extends React.Component<any, any> {
Item: React.FunctionComponent<any>
}
```

how in the world do I add List.Item as an attribute of the type "list"?? I have tried overriding it by defining a second class/interface that extends the first, tried using a constructor to assign it to 'this', and tried the above, but none did the job

Answer (score 0):

turns out I just needed "static" on my Item field in my List class. that was extremely hard to find